# How to add dynamic additional attributes into a junction table with ManyToMany association in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I created a **many-to-many** association by **sequelize** in my koa app. But I had no idea on how to create additional attributes in the junction table. Thanks.

I referred to the official doc of sequelize but didn't find a solution. In brief:

"an order can have many items"

"an item can exist in many orders"

Then I created OrderItems as junction table.

But I have trouble in **inserting value into the junction table**

```
// definitions
const Item = sequelize.define('item', itemSchema);
const Order = sequelize.define('order', orderSchema);

// junction table
const OrderItems = sequelize.define('order_item', {
  item_quantity: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER } // number of a certain item in a certain order.
});

// association
Item.belongsToMany(Order, { through: OrderItems, foreignKey: 'item_id' });
Order.belongsToMany(Item, { through: OrderItems, foreignKey: 'order_id' });

// insert value
const itemVals = [{ name: 'foo', price: 6 }, { name: 'bar', price: 7 }];
const orderVals = [
  {
    date: '2019-01-06',
    items: [{ name: 'foo', item_quantity: 12 }]
  },
  {
    date: '2019-01-07',
    items: [{ name: 'foo', item_quantity: 14 }]
  }
]
items = Item.bulkCreate(itemVals)
orders = Order.bulkCreate(orderVals)

//Questions here: create entries in junction table
for (let order of orders) {
  const itemsInOrder = Item.findAll({
    where: {
      name: {
        [Op.in]: order.items.map(item => item.name)
      }
    }
  })
  order.addItems(itemsInOrder, {
    through: {
      item_quantity: 'How to solve here?'
    }
  })
}

// my current manual solution: 
// need to configure column names in junction table manually.
// Just like what we do in native SQL.
const junctionValList =[]
for (let orderVal of orderVals) {
  orderVal.id = (await Order.findOne(/* get order id */)).dataValues.id
  for (let itemVal of orderVal.items) {
    itemVal.id = (await Item.findOne(/* get item id similarly */)).dataValues.id
    const entyInJunctionTable = {
      item_id: itemVal.id,
      order_id: orderVal.id,
      item_quantity: itemVal.item_quantity
    }
    junctionValList.push(entyInJunctionTable)
  }
}
OrderItems.bulkCreate(junctionValList).then(/* */).catch(/* */)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that this script it's for seeding purpose you can do something like this:

```
/*
  Create an array in which all promises will be stored.
  We use it like this because async/await are not allowed inside of 'for', 'map' etc.
*/
const promises = orderVals.map((orderVal) => {
  // 1. Create the order
  return Order.create({ date: orderVal.date, /* + other properties */ }).then((order) => {
    // 2. For each item mentioned in 'orderVal.items'...
    return orderVal.items.map((orderedItem) => {
      // ...get the DB instance
      return Item.findOne({ where: { name: orderedItem.name } }).then((item) => {
        // 3. Associate it with current order
        return order.addItem(item.id, { through: { item_quantity: orderedItem.item_quantity } });
      });
    });
  });
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

But it's not an efficient way to do it in general. First of all, there are a lot of nested functions. But the biggest problem is that you associate items with the orders, based on their name and it's possible that in the future you will have multiple items with the same name.

You should try to use an item id, this way you will be sure about the outcome and also the script it will be much shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much ~ you're right that I'm using it as the purpose of seeding. I'll try your method and improve my definition of the schema and association.

Comment: For sure ~ and if there were any other issues that I would be puzzled with, I shall consult you again :-P best regards.